# index not being transferred from uicollectionviewcell to view controller

Tags: indexing, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell, option-type

My code below is not working and is causing a runtime error. Stating Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I don't know what is causing this. I don't know how to fix the optional issue in this. The code for cellforitemat has also been added.

```
class antion : UICollectionViewCell {
      @IBOutlet var sam : UILabel!


      var deleagete : DataCollectionProtocoe?
      var index : IndexPath?

     @IBAction func press(){
            deleagete?.passData(indx: (index?.row)!)
     }

    @IBAction func delete(){
           deleagete?.deleteData(indx: (index?.row)!)
    }

 }


extension ViewController : DataCollectionProtocoe {
         func passData(indx: Int) {
              let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVDC") as? DetailVDC
              vc?.name = people[indx].name!
              self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

        }

       func deleteData(indx: Int) {
            people.remove(at: indx)
            cc.reloadData()
       }
}

protocol DataCollectionProtocoe {
         func passData(indx:Int)
         func deleteData(indx:Int)
}

class DetailVDC: UIViewController {
      var name = ""

      @IBOutlet var lbl : UILabel!

     override func viewDidLoad() {   
              lbl.text = name        
     }
}


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! antion








    cell.index = indexPath
    cell.deleagete = self
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Where you assign `DataCollectionProtocoe` in `viewcontroller` ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what little i could understand from your code, it looks like you are creating the UICollectionViewCell instance but not setting any value to the delegate property of the cell.

When you create an instance of the collection view cell in the controller , assign the controller to the delegate property of the cell as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = antion()
        cell.delegate = self // assuming the controller is the data source of the collection view
}
```

Comment: I have that code I added to the end. I tried your code it did not work.

Comment: Enable zombie objects in Scheme diagnostics to identify which line is causing the crash. Also enable exception breakpoints for more help.